# Google App Engine .jsp Problem

Tags: google-app-engine

I just created a .jsp file in my google app engine project. How to resolve the below error.

**Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
Your project must be configured to use a JDK in order to use JSPs**

**proj1.jsp**

**/Proj1/war    Unknown Google App Engine Problem**

Kindly let me know.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

it is the error. In order to compile jsp you need a jdk installed in your system. If you are running on a JRE you will get this error. Also make sure that your project has been configured with a jdk in it's path.

Comment: I already have JDK in my computer. But still the error. You mean jdk for Java enterprise edition?

Comment: I have rectified this error by doing this :Make sure you have a JDK installed.  You can get one here:
http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/index.jsp.  By default this installed to (In
Windows) C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_14
- In Eclipse, go to: Window->Preferences->Java->Installed JREs and check to see if
you have an entry for the path from the previous step.  If not, then Click
add->Standard VM, then for the JRE Path enter the path from the previous step.  You
should see all of the JARs added to the library section.
- If you had a JRE checked previously(as I did) then you can uncheck it.

Comment: I think that's what i meant , make sure your project has been configured with a jdk in it's path

Comment: @ Abdul Well Thanks for your inputs.

Comment: For some reason, a Google Eclipse plugin deleted my JDK!

Answer (score 13):

For sake of improving answers

**stack over flow reference**

[.jsp file not working for Google App Engine guestbook tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3112497/jsp-file-not-working-for-google-app-engine-guestbook-tutorial)

**the accepted answer was a year ago**

***updated answer from reference***

In the end I seem to have wasted my bounty as I found the solution (with a little help) myself.

The problem arose because I was unfamiliar with Eclipse. When I found the more verbose error message **`Your project must be configured to use a JDK in order to use JSPs guestbook.jsp`**.
It was located in a tab called **'Markers'** in pane found at the bottom of the Eclipse window.
[image]
It seems that Eclipse wasn't aware that I had installed the **JDK**.

In Eclipse I went to menu **`Window->Preferences->Java->Installed JREs`** . Eclipse had only one entry there named **`jre6`** I clicked the `Add...` button Chose `Standard VM` and browsed to the base directory of the jdk (in my case **`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20`**)

I rebuilt my project but the same error was there. I had forgotten to check the box that tells Eclipse to use the **jdk** instead of the **jre**.
[image]

As soon as I did that Eclipse rebuilt my project and the error was gone.

Comment: Thanks for the details!  I had already created my project but under "Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries" I still had to "Add Library" the JDK and **remove** the existing JRE library.  Now it works for me.

Answer (score 8):

To solve this problem, first please confirm that JDK is already install on your computer. If it not available, go to [Oracle JDK hompage](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-6u27-download-440405.html) to download and install it.

Then follow [some steps](http://techiedan.com/2009/10/19/set-up-jdk-in-eclipse/) to config JDK.

When JDK is configured, return eclipse and build project if you still get current error, I decide you are using JRE instead JDK. Choose Prefrences - Java - Install JRE - Un-check JRE and check JDK

Rebuild project

Hope this help!

Answer (score 2):

Set JDK as your Installed JREs in Eclipse.
In Eclipse Window->Preference->Java->Installed JREs
Click on Add Button | Select VM ->Add JRE
Select Folder of jdk as "JRE Home" Directory.
Click OK.
Build your GAE Project

Answer (score 0):

JFTR:

**For those who use Ubuntu and OpenJDK**, and may come here looking for help on the same issue: EVEN when it is called Open**JDK** (i.e. java-6-openjdk) actually you may have installed only the JRE part since they are on different packages, so you need to install also the JDK. For version 6 this is done via:

```
$ sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jdk
```

Note that you may have yet an openjdk-6-jre in your system.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem persist, you must sure that in your project use JDK library. Go to your project->click right->Build Path->**Configure Build Path**->Add library->JRE System Library->Select "*Workspace default JRE (jdk1...)*"->Finish, and in "**Order and Export**" **UP** your **JDK Library** above JRE Library. When you save your proyect it´s ok.